# What are the main differences in file implementation between linux ext4 and wi dows 10 ntfs at low level?

Tags: operating-systems

I need help with this is possible. Could someone who has a good understanding of Linux and Windows explain how they differ in file implementation foxuing on low level end? There isn't a huge amount of literature on this, thanks.

Comment: I suspect this might be too broad to be a good fit here -- there are probably too many differences to list.  Any votes from the community, one way or the other?

Comment: [Ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/) is well-documented, and since it is Open Source, if the docs are lacking, you can [read the code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tytso/ext4.git/tree/fs/ext4?h=dev). NTFS has been reverse-engineered and [documented by the Linux-NTFS project](https://web.archive.org/web/20070929163444/http://www.linux-ntfs.org/content/view/103/42/). This documentation is so good it is reportedly even used internally at Microsoft. It documents NTFS 3.1 which was shipped with Windows XP. While that does sound old, there hasn't been a newer version since then.